# Pushing to cocoapods get an error `resource_bundles`

Tags: cocoapods

After pushing code to GitHub do the next to push to Cocoapods:

`git tag 0.1.1` and `git push origin 0.1.1`everything is ok,

but when perform pushing .podspec file to Cocoapods `pod trunk push ASAutoResizingTextView.podspec` get the next error

- ERROR | [iOS] file patterns: The `resource_bundles` pattern for `ASAutoResizingTextView` did not match any file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this problem I just comment next in .podspec file

```
#s.resource_bundles = {
#'ASAutoResizingTextView' => ['Pod/Assets/*.png']
#}
```